# array to obj in plain JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array and need to make an object from it with combining keys/values. Any ideas how to go 1. recursively and 2. without recursion-
in plain JS without any external libs (like underscore, Lodash, ...)

```
[
    [
        ['firstName', 'Eren'], ['lastName', 'Duran'], ['age', 22], ['role', 'admin']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Sallito'], ['lastName', 'Jordan'], ['age', 16], ['role', 'server']
    ]
]
```

Should become:

```
  [
        {firstName: 'Eren', lastName: 'Duran', age: 22, role: 'admin'},
        {firstName: 'Sallito', lastName: 'Jordan', age: 16, role: 'server'}
    ]
```

Comment: how do you expect a recursice approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative approach with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var array = [[['firstName', 'Eren'], ['lastName', 'Duran'], ['age', 22], ['role', 'admin']], [['firstName', 'Sallito'], ['lastName', 'Jordan'], ['age', 16], ['role', 'server']]],
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        var object = {};
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            object[b[0]] = b[1];
        });
        return object;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```